# when i turn this scraping code the result is empty

Tags: python, scrapy

i try with this code to scrape html data from this site but the result is always empty .
https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/montpellier-34/alco/140769091.htm?ci=340172&idtt=2,5&idtypebien=2,1&naturebien=1,2,4&tri=initial&bd=ListToDetail

```
    def parse(self, response):
    content = response.css(".agence-adresse::text").extract()
    yield{'adresse =' :content}
```

Comment: 1) do not use more than one exclamation mark, best don't use them in any number when asking a question. 2) read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  4) Edit your question according to 3. 5) format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This css.

```
css = '.agence-adresse ::text'
content = response.css(css).extract()
yield {
    'address': content,
}
```

[image: scraping your given page/attribtue]

Comment: where should i place yield....

Comment: refer to updated answer

Comment: the same error i get this {'address': []}

Comment: Please post you code here, as i can receive the response in my scrapy shell.

Comment: import scrapy


class selogerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "seloger"
    start_urls = [
'https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/montpellier-34/alco/140769091.htm?ci=340172&idtt=2,5&idtypebien=2,1&naturebien=1,2,4&tri=initial&bd=ListToDetail'    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        css = '.agence-adresse ::text'
        content = response.css(css).extract()
        yield {
            'address': content,
        }

Comment: that's my code.

Comment: i use an IDE PYCHARM

Comment: have you tried it on scrapy shell ?

Comment: no i didn't try it

Comment: have an idea why it doesn't work on pycharm

Comment: i try to run it on the shell but  i didn't get any result